# How to import contacts from VCF file by using code

Tags: android, import-contacts

I have create a vcf file that contains contacts by using this code

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
String lookupKey = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);
                        System.out.println("The value is " + cr.getType(uri));
                        AssetFileDescriptor fd = this.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
                        FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
```

how can I import this file into the device by code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching the Web the best way to import contacts is as follows

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
             int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();
             ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                      .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE,null)
                      .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                      .withValue(RawContacts.STARRED, Starred)
                      .withValue(RawContacts.CUSTOM_RINGTONE, CustRingTone)
                      .build());

             ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                      .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                      .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                      .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName)
                      .withValue(StructuredName.PHONETIC_GIVEN_NAME, PhoneticName_First)
                      .withValue(StructuredName.PHONETIC_MIDDLE_NAME, PhoneticName_Middle)
                      .withValue(StructuredName.PHONETIC_FAMILY_NAME, PhoneticName_Last)
                      .build());

             for (RowData phone : phones) {
                 ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                          .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                          .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                          .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, phone.data)
                          .withValue(Phone.TYPE, phone.type)
                          .withValue(Phone.LABEL, phone.customLabel)
                          .build());
                }
```