# How to import vcf file

Tags: android, vcf-vcard

i have exported my contact to VCF file on SDCard. Now, i want to import back but i don't know how to do that. Please give me some code or advice. Thank so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below Code for import contacts from .vcf file.

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE,null)
        .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
        .withValue(RawContacts.STARRED, Starred)
        .withValue(RawContacts.CUSTOM_RINGTONE, CustRingTone)
        .build());

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
        .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName)
        .withValue(StructuredName.PHONETIC_GIVEN_NAME, PhoneticName_First)
        .withValue(StructuredName.PHONETIC_MIDDLE_NAME, PhoneticName_Middle)
        .withValue(StructuredName.PHONETIC_FAMILY_NAME, PhoneticName_Last)
        .build());

for (RowData phone : phones) {
    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI).withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex).withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE).withValue(Phone.NUMBER, phone.data).withValue(Phone.TYPE, phone.type).withValue(Phone.LABEL, phone.customLabel).build());
}
```

And see below link for more information.

[How to import contacts from VCF file by using code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11312507/1466188)