# How to restore contacts in android from .vcf file without using Intents

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

Hi `stackoverflow` I'm trying to develop an application which can `backup` and `restore` contacts, `backup` is fine, I'm using the below approach to backup contact as `VCF` format file

```
public static void getVCF() {
    final String vfile = "contacts.vcf";

    Cursor phones = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
            null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
    phones.moveToFirst();

    for (int i = 0; i < phones.getCount(); i++) {

        String lookupKey = phones.getString(phones
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));

        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI, lookupKey);

        AssetFileDescriptor fd;
        try {
            fd = mContext.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri,
                    "r");
            FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
            fis.read(buf);
            String VCard = new String(buf);
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString() + File.separator + vfile;
            FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path,
                    true);
            mFileOutputStream.write(VCard.toString().getBytes());
            phones.moveToNext();
            Log.d("Vcard", VCard);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But `restore` is the mystery, I searched a lot in Internet but  no success, I've tried to `backup` using `Intent`, but that's not the solution for the problem, the code is as follows

```
            final Intent intent = new Intent();

            final MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            String tmptype = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension("vcf");
            final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +"/contacts.vcf");

            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),tmptype);
            startActivity(intent);
```

`Permissions`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I want to `restore` the contacts properly by not using `Intents`. I've come across these posts which are informative [How to import contacts from VCF file by using code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696873/how-to-import-contacts-from-vcf-file-by-using-code/11312507#11312507)
But I ended up with confusion of how to use the code, can any one please help me to solve this puzzle.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you try to use your 'Intent' solution as detailed above? There appears to be no activity associated with your intent.

Comment: A `dialog` will appear to choose the application to run `VCF` @Kerry