# How to import the contacts from vcf file stored in sdcard programically in android

Tags: android, contacts, vcf-vcard

I stored the vcf file in Sdcard but now i have to import that vcf file in contacts programicaly

i have created the vcf file by following code

```
final String vfile = "Contacts.vcf";
Cursor phones = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);
phones.moveToFirst();
for (int i = 0; i < phones.getCount(); i++) {
    String lookupKey = phones.getString(phones
        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI,lookupKey);
    AssetFileDescriptor fd;
    try {
            fd = mContext.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
            FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
            fis.read(buf);
            String VCard = new String(buf);
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .toString() + File.separator + vfile;
            FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path,true);
            mFileOutputStream.write(VCard.toString().getBytes());
            phones.moveToNext();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

by this contact.vcf is created in sdcard
-now i have to import this vcf file in contacts programicaly

and by using following code i have restore the vcf file

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/x-vcard");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

startActivity(intent);
```

-but not syncing the contacts by using this code

Comment: Check this link:-https://stackoverflow.com/a/11312507/2919483

Comment: Rajshree Tiwari not working

Comment: then try this :- Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(storage_path+vfile)),"text/x-vcard"); //storage path is path of your vcf file and vFile is name of that file.
startActivity(intent);

Comment: yes i have tried this 
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(uri,"text/x-vcard");
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);

Comment: but after some time contacts stop.generally after importing the vcf file in contacts it should merge and contacts get double but not working

Comment: you mean to say it is not syncing contact right?

Comment: yes exactly it was not syncing and after sometime contacts stop

Comment: Can you post your full code please, i check it at my end

Comment: below i have added please check.above it was for export and below it was for import i have used

Comment: Dear delete that answer, it shows that you are answering your own question, it will be marked negative, i said post means edit your question which you asked, add the code in your current question

Comment: Pooja do one thing share your full class from this link :-  https://codeshare.io/ayZ7wz   , paste your whole code here and share the link with me here

Comment: i have added my source code for restoring

Comment: okay i check ...

Comment: https://codeshare.io/ayZ7wz please check the link

Comment: have you added  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/> this permission?

Comment: yes i have added

Comment: pooja your first code is nor working i am getting negative arrysize exception, qare you getting this error?

Comment: in which line you are getting this exception?